# Trouble referring to an object inside of a method

Tags: c#

```
internal class Program
{
    public class Creature
    {
        public int health;
        public int damage;
        public int coins;
    }

    public static void Hit()
    {
        yourCharacter.health = -10;
        //^^THIS IS THE ERROR^^//
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Creature yourCharacter = new Creature();
        yourCharacter.health = 100;
        yourCharacter.damage = 1;
        yourCharacter.coins = 0;
        Hit();
    }
}
```

I tried to mention an integer in an object (that being "yourCharacter.health") from a method. I received an error stating that "yourCharacter.health does not exist in this current context." I assume its because I need to let the program know what "yourCharacter.health" actually is while trying to mention it there. is there anything I can do to define "yourCharacter.health" before AND after "Hit" so I am not getting an error?

Comment: yourCharacter is not defined and hence this code won't compile

Comment: More specifically (to the above comment), although yourCharacter IS a local variable in main, that variable is not at all visible within the Hit function. You can either pass it as a parameter, or move the Hit function as a member of the Creature class, or a variety of other approaches. 
FWIW, it is generally considered bad form to use fields like this as public variables. Better to define them as properties, such as public int Health { get; set; } Comments are too short to explain why, but any good book or article on properties will explain why.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Fraser! I am also watching guides and practicing getting and setting, but I don't think I understand it enough to incorporate it into my code yet, nonetheless, It compiles Just fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide if (1) "your creature is being hit" or (2) "your program is hitting your creature".

If it's (1) then Jonathan Dodd's code is correct. `Hit` moves inside the `class Creature`.

```
internal class Program
{
    public class Creature
    {
        public int Health;
        public int Damage;
        public int Coins;

        public void Hit()
        {
            this.Health = -10;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Creature yourCharacter = new Creature();
        yourCharacter.Health = 100;
        yourCharacter.Damage = 1;
        yourCharacter.Coins = 0;
        yourCharacter.Hit();
    }
}
```

If it's (2) then you need to pass the `Creature` to the `Hit` method, like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    public class Creature
    {
        public int Health;
        public int Damage;
        public int Coins;
    }

    public static void Hit(Creature yourCharacter)
    {
        yourCharacter.Health = -10;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Creature yourCharacter = new Creature();
        yourCharacter.Health = 100;
        yourCharacter.Damage = 1;
        yourCharacter.Coins = 0;
        Hit(yourCharacter);
    }
}
```

Please note: I change the naming of your fields to use Pascal-case as per C# standards.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like the following:

```cs
namespace Example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class Creature
        {
            public int health;
            public int damage;
            public int coins;

            public void Hit()
            {
                this.health = -10;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Creature yourCharacter = new Creature();
            yourCharacter.health = 100;
            yourCharacter.damage = 1;
            yourCharacter.coins = 0;

            yourCharacter.Hit();
        }
    }
}
```

In this version of the code, `Hit()` is a member method of the `Creature` type.

**Update**

In OOD methods can be considered to be messages to the object. The `Hit()` method is a message to a `Creature` object that the creature has been hit.

The state of an object should be managed by the object. Messages to the object can change the state but the object should be interpreting and handling the messages.

The state of a `Creature` can be encapsulated by using properties instead of public fields.

In the following example code, the `Creature` state is encapsulated behind properties, `Hit()` takes an amount of damage, and a `Creature` may have a damage resistance factor. This is just to demonstrate that there could be many instances of `Creature` and the consequence of a hit can be different for each instance.

```cs
namespace Example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class Creature
        {
            public Creature(int health, int damage, int coins, double damageResistance)
            {
                Health = health;
                Damage = damage;
                Coins = coins;
                DamageResistance = damageResistance;
            }

            public int Health { get; private set; }

            public int Damage { get; private set; }

            public int Coins { get; private set; }

            public double DamageResistance { get; private set; }

            public void Hit(int damage)
            {
                Health -= (int)(damage * DamageResistance);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Creature yourCharacter = new Creature(100, 1, 0, 0.10);

            yourCharacter.Hit(10);
        }
    }
}
```