# Trouble with passing parameters through a method

Tags: c#

```
internal class Program
{
    public class Creature
    {
        public int health;
        public int damage;
        public int coins;
    }

    public static void Hit(Creature yourCharacter)
    {
        yourCharacter.health = -10;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Creature yourCharacter = new Creature();
        yourCharacter.health = 100;
        yourCharacter.damage = 1;
        yourCharacter.coins = 0;
        Hit(); <<ERROR
    }
}
```

Hello! My main program is having errors so I created a short example above. I am having trouble using "Hit()" in this example because Visual Studio recommends I add "(Creature yourCharacter)" to the list, but trying to just put them in gives off an error "program creature is a type which is not valid in the given context." is there a separate way to run "Hit" from my main program or am I going about this all wrong? in the final product I want to be able to use "hit" from my main program, because It will happen multiple times and include a lot more than just one line of code. Thank you for the help!
Elias

Comment: Your `Hit` method declares that it has a parameter - you're not specifying any arguments. You want `Hit(yourCharacter)`, specifying the argument that's used as the initial value for the parameter.

Comment: (Fundamentally, I would strongly recommend that you read a good C# book or tutorial - you shouldn't need to rely on autocomplete to fix errors like this.)

Comment: You've already asked almost the same question here and it already has an answer that applies to this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751219/trouble-referring-to-an-object-inside-of-a-method

Answer (score -1):

The `Hit(Creature yourCharacter)` method requires the `Creature` parameter

You need to call the method like this:

```
Hit(yourCharacter);
```